# React Custom Table Sort

Tags: reactjs, sorting

I'm trying to implement a custom table sort in React to sort when click on the header.

After I click on a header, the component is not render with the new posts array. Why?
I'm trying to make it work without using a framework or library.

Thanks

*** I updated the code with the an option to first click sort asc and second click change too desc. The sorting is all messed. Is there something wrong with my sort function or my map where I keep the last sorted option?

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';

const Sort = () => {
    const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
    
    const keySort = new Map();
    keySort.set("id", 0);
    keySort.set("title", 0);
    keySort.set("body", 0);

    useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchData() {
            const data = await axios.get(url);
            if(data.status !== 200) 
                console.error(data.statusText);
            else {
                setPosts(data.data);
            }
        }
        fetchData();
    }, []);

    const handleHeaderClick = (event) => {
        const id = event.target.id;
        setPosts((currPosts) => [...currPosts].sort((a,b) => {
            const keySortState = keySort.get(id) || 0;
            if(keySortState >= 0) {
                keySort.set(id, -1)
                if(a[id] > b[id])   return 1
                if(a[id] < b[id])   return -1
                return 0;
            }
            keySort.set(id, 0)
            if(a[id] > b[id])   return -1
            if(a[id] < b[id])   return 1
            return 0;   
        }));
    }

    return (
        <>
            <p>Sort Page</p>
            <table style={{border: '1px solid'}}>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th id="id" onClick={handleHeaderClick}>id</th>
                        <th id="title" onClick={handleHeaderClick}>Title</th>
                        <th id="body" onClick={handleHeaderClick}>Body</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {posts.map((obj, index) => {
                        return (
                            <tr key={index}>
                                <td>{obj.id}</td>
                                <td>{obj.title}</td>
                                <td>{obj.body}</td>
                            </tr>
                        )
                    })}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </>
    );
}

export default Sort;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change  `const data = posts` to  `const data = [...posts]` Because you're mutating the original state.

Also you need to change the sort function to:

```
data.sort((a, b) => {
  if(a[id] < b[id]) return -1;
  if(a[id] > b[id]) return 1;
});
```

Here's the code:

```
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";

const Sort = () => {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      const data = await axios.get(url);
      if (data.status !== 200) console.error(data.statusText);
      else {
        setPosts(data.data);
      }
    }
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  const handleHeaderClick = (event) => {
    const id = event.target.id;
    const data = [...posts];
    data.sort((a, b) => {
      if(a[id] < b[id]) return -1;
      if(a[id] > b[id]) return 1;
    });
    setPosts(data);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <p>Sort Page</p>
      <table style={{ border: "1px solid" }}>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th
              id="id"
              style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
              onClick={handleHeaderClick}
            >
              id
            </th>
            <th
              id="title"
              style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
              onClick={handleHeaderClick}
            >
              Title
            </th>
            <th
              id="body"
              style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
              onClick={handleHeaderClick}
            >
              Body
            </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {posts.map((obj, index) => {
            return (
              <tr key={index}>
                <td>{obj.id}</td>
                <td>{obj.title}</td>
                <td>{obj.body}</td>
              </tr>
            );
          })}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return <Sort />;
}
```

[image: Edit hardcore-gagarin-5gf88]

Comment: It is better to pass `setState` a function a base your changes on that state, you can read in my answer why.

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to manage the state to sort asc or desc depending on the current order? I mean, change the current order

Comment: @myTest532myTest532 Yes. It's possible. If you would like to achieve that, please leave a comment to updated my answer.

Comment: Yes, please if you have an example of how to do it

Comment: I just updated the code with my attempt, but it's sorting in an odd way

Comment: @myTest532myTest532 Please check the codesanbox again. I've updated the code for achieving both ascending and descending sort.

Comment: Thank you. It just needs some adjustments to save the sort order of each column.

Answer (score 1):

When mutating state in React, you should never mutate the original state object.
Your mistake was in this line `const data = posts;`, you passed `data` the reference of `posts` and thus modified the original object.
Instead, you should have send `setState` a callback function, which accepts the current `posts` array and then spread it - `...` and modify it the way you wanted.
You can read in the [React official docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) why it's better to pass `setState` a funciton.

How it should look :

```
  const handleHeaderClick = (event) => {
    const id = event.target.id;
    setPosts((currPosts) => [...currPosts].sort((a,b) => b[id] - a[id]));
}
```